# .NET Indirect Localized String Resource

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a .NET Framework 4.8 app and need to be able to specify an "indirect localized string resource" in a registry key (for FriendlyTypeName for a file association).  It should look like `@pathToExe,-5` or such.  How do I embed a string resource into a C# program with a specific numeric ID that I can reference in the registry key?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to be able to access a localized string resource from code like this: `MyStrings.SomeString`?

Comment: @ewerspej No.  From [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-progids#programmatic-identifier-elements-used-by-file-associations), under "FriendlyTypeName", it says "it must be formatted as an indirect string (a fully qualified file name and resource value preceded by the @ symbol), for instance @%SystemRoot%\shell32.dll,-154".  In their example they're getting (I think) the 154th string resource from shell32.dll.  I need to provide my own string from my own (.net) exe, but don't know how to do that.